# Windows 8 app - load a different default.html file based on resolution

Tags: windows-8, screen-resolution

I have a pretty basic HTML/JavaScript app that I'm putting into a Windows 8 app.  Most of it's image based and doesn't really fit the standard way of designing for different resolutions.

I've created it in several different resolutions and basically what I want to be able to do is tell it to load a different "default.html" file depending on the screen resolution of the device.  I'm not having any luck finding information on how to do this.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the screen resolution of the device (and not just the size of your window), you will need to [use a WinRT component written in C++](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2012/07/24/get-screen-resolution-in-windows-8-metro-style-application.aspx).  This component can be [called from your Javascript app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755833.aspx).  You would call this component in your [app.onactivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212679.aspx) handler and show the appropriate content based on the resolution.

The start page (default.html) is defined in your app manifest and you can't change it by logic.  But, as above, there is no need to.  Just start on default.html, check the resolution and show the content you want (show and hide divs for example based on the resolution).

Answer (score 0):

The Default.html page is the default page for your Windows 8 app. Which inturn is defined in the Manifest file of your app, **package.appxmanifest**. There you set the main page for your app, alongwith some other App Settings.

You cannot change that by using an if else block for the Screen Resolution, such as:

```
if(screen.width > 1788) {
   default.page == "someotherpage";
}
```

Nope. That won't happen.

However, since you're using the HTML, CSS, JavaScript, why not do what we Web Developers do with our websites. We check for the screen resolution. And depending on that, we alter the content.

Otherwise, it won't be possible to edit and change the App Manifest file at the run time.